# How can I access a custom variable in config/application.rb from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom variable in my `config/application.rb` that I want to access from one of my models.

The variable is defined in `config/application.rb` like so:

`config.default_page_logo = 'pagelogo.png'`

And I'm trying to access it from the model in a method roughly similar to this:

`def logo_type
  logo = client.logo if is_client && client.has_logo
  logo || Rails.configuration.default_page_logo
end`

In the browser I get the following error: 
`NoMethodError in Home#dashboard`

`undefined method 'default_page_logo' for Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000564b1b468680`

I'm running Ruby 2.4.3 and Rails 5.1.4

Comment: did you restart server before accessing the config?

Answer (score 1):

`Rails.application.config.default_page_logo`

But better solution is https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic